# Is this stack or stack emulation?

Tags: java, stack

```
package java.util;
public
class Stack<E> extends Vector<E> {
    public Stack() {
    }

    public E push(E item) {
        addElement(item);
        return item;
    }

    public synchronized E pop() {
        E obj;
        int len = size();

        obj = peek();
        removeElementAt(len - 1);

        return obj;
    }

    public synchronized E peek() {
        int     len = size();

        if (len == 0)
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        return elementAt(len - 1);
    }

    public synchronized int search(Object o) {
        int i = lastIndexOf(o);

        if (i >= 0) {
            return size() - i;
        }
        return -1;
    }


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1224463164541339165L;
}
```

Above is the java source code for stack.
I realized that it is only emulating a stack and not a real one.So my questions are

1. Am I right in saying that this is just an imitation of Stack and not the real one?
2. If I can say the above and I want to build it from scratch,how would I do it?(arrays of fixed size or arraylist which in turn uses list(single/double linked)?)

Comment: Above is a link to all things called stack in grepcode. What are you actually asking about?

Comment: `java.util.Stack` is an implementation of a stack data structure. I'm not sure what you mean by "emulation".

Comment: I mean on a fundamental level I think stacks should run on arrays which in turn run on references to memory. So the above class implements Lists and Collections. from this my questions above follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no "real Stack", a stack is just an idea, a so-called [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). It supports two operations, push and pop, and the order of elements is defined to be last-in first-out (LIFO). In addition to java.util.Stack (based on Vector, which is array-based), you also have java.util.LinkedList (a doubly-linked list), which also supports stack operations, so it's also a stack as much as the other one.. There are several other implementations, for example all implementations of java.util.Deque.
2. You can do it from scratch in a number of ways, each has their own trade-offs. Your question is not defined enough for a good answer.

Comment: I understand it. Well, here's my argument java.util.Stack implements Linked list which are primarily queues. So this abstract data type should have and independent  implementation. But that is not what's happening here.Hence I say its imitating the stack.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's primarily X, nor is it possible to even say if LinkedList is primarily a queue, a stack, a deque or a list - it's all of those, because you can use it as all of those..

Comment: If LinkedList is "imitating a stack", then all stack implementations are "imitating a stack". If LinkedList "is a stack" then all stack implementations "are stacks". The distinction you're making does not make sense, because a stack is just an idea, a contract, a protocol, if you will. You could implement a stack using a printer, a robotic arm, and a scanner, and it would be terribly complex and inefficient, but you could and it'd still be/imitate a stack in exactly the same way as LinkedList does.

Comment: thanks! so these are just ideas that are implemented in anyway necessary.